# Cannot copy to file share located in D: volume

Tags: windows, file-permissions

I have a service running on a machine (Call this Machine A) that generates files and copies those files to a remote share on another machine (Machine B).

Machine B, I had two shares set up:
One on the C volume (Share C), and    one in the D volume (Share D).

Machine A can copy files to Share C without any problems; however it has issues copying to Share D.

I have triple checked to see that Share C and Share D have the same permission settings so I am at a loss of why I can't copy to share D. I've even given full access to everybody on the D: volume itself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You're clear that you've verified the NT Share permissions and the NTFS file permissions ?

Think of them as the share is the outer door and your file perms are the inner hatch and the most restrictive setting will determine your level of network access.

Assuming you've verified the same user in your current problem can successfully write the \machineB\Dshare if logged on locally to MachineB, then it is likely your Share perms are the issue.

Sec compatibility issues can arise if the versions vary widely between Windows, such as an "antiquated" version of Windows XP trying to access a skyhigh modernized 2012 Server share but that doesn't seem likely since those issues prevent any connectivity and your successfully accessing \MachineB\CShare.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Not sure it was the share permission. I can manually copy files to share D from Machine A, however the service was couldn't copy over the error. So it seemed like a user specific issue which I didn't understand because share D had same permissions as share C. Someone suggested I try giving full permission for Machine A itself and not just users and that WORKED. Still confused what makes Share D different from Share C...

Comment: I'm signing off and I should've asked which version of Windows your principals are using, I'm liternally in overload an the moment from the inundation of the resource kit utilities and other binaries capable of listing perms and it's worth asking how and which methods besides right clicking and viewing the GUI listed ACL's of the troublesome D share.

Comment: Good news, (I'm literally late), you're going to get crushed with advice of mixed quality but you'll have no shortage of methods to learn why \\MachineB\DShare is problematic.  Ask yourself, how confident are you in your familiarity of Windows Security? The nuances are laborious and if you're honest with yourself, this might be a good time to spend a few pennies on any used copy of any Microsoft Press book on the topic that Amazon sellers offer in vast quanitiies.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "giving full permission for Machine A". I did not think you could assign entire machines to permissions.